# "Begin with the end in mind" alternatives?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there an alternative word/phrase (preferably shorter) to describe "begin with the end in mind"? I am looking for a term for that approach or style of doing something. Let's ignore that it is actually one of the seven habits of bla bla bla. I am trying to find a term like "reverse calculation" — a step-by-step approach, but from the end to the start.

> I started working on the car from scratch, taking a *begin with the end in mind* approach.

I want to replace that with something shorter:

> I started working on the car from scratch, taking a [ABC] approach.

Compare the commonly used, although different in meaning, the "STAR" method, which basically is short for "Situation, Task, Action, Result".

> The STAR method is a structured manner of responding to a behavioral-based interview question by discussing the specific situation, task, action, and result of the situation you are describing.

Yeah, I don't think I can write "BWTEIM".

Comment: Have you considered 'prophylactic', or 'preemptive'? I don't think there's a word _specifically_ for this concept, so maybe consider these possibilities and see which makes more sense in your context.

Comment: I don't think there's a single word for it, but maybe something like ["keeping in mind the goal"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keeping+in+mind+the+goal&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeeping%20in%20mind%20the%20goal%3B%2Cc0)?